# Can a Decanter of Endless Water be changed to produce other liquids?

Tags: magic-items, dnd-3e

Is there any way to have a [Decanter of Endless Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/decanter-of-endless-water) pour out other drinkable liquids? If so, how could I get one? It seems reasonable to me as a possibility. If not how might you go about modifying a decanter of endless water to do so?

Comment: Excellent, we’re heading in the right direction. Now, are you asking a lore question about the Decanter of Endless Water, or are you asking if it’s possible within the scope of the rules to create, say, a decanter of endless whisky?

Comment: Lore question with a hint of rules

Comment: Is this really a lore question?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it’s more likely a rule question rather than a lore question.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit because it is unclear what OP is actually asking. They've 'clarified' twice now with different foci. They need to be the ones to clarify what they are asking.

Comment: The last edit seems to have changed the tag of the question from dnd-5e to dnd-3e. This does not seem to be a good idea; particularly for a question that was asked and answered over a year ago.

Comment: Abraham, did you intend to change this question from being about 5th edition D&D to being about 3rd edition D&D?

Comment: Yup I indeed did mean to change the edition as I just realized that it might fit in dnd 3.5

Comment: Are you playing 3.X or are you playing 5e? Changing the edition on this question invalidates all of the existing answers. Additionally, I would want to see some more details before reopening this. Are you asking as a player, or as a DM? Are you interested in modifying a Decanter you already have to produce some other liquid, or are you just wondering if it's possible to find/purchase/craft a variation on the Decanter that inherently produces some other liquid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's Up To Your DM

Technically, the rulebooks have no Decanter of Endless (Insert any liquid here) among the plethora of items Wizards presents us with, however that doesn't mean that is impossible. In the DMG, in Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop on page 284, we are presented with the "Modifying An Item" section, which, since I am not going to quote the whole section, suggests three types of changes: Cosmetic, Property, and Fusing Items. I'd say your thing would fit under the property section, where it gives examples like changing an object's damage type or effect. As a player, this is off-limits. Speak to your DM, and they might allow it.**The Rules are guidelines, rather than rules. It's up to the individual DM to decide how much they want to stick to them. ;)**

Otherwise I'd agree with Thomas and say Alchemy Jug is your best bet.

Comment: P.S. If you ever find a Decanter of Endless Ketchup, Leave it in the dark corner of the tavern for me.

Comment: I call dibs on the Decanter of Endless Gin ^^

Answer (score 8):

#### Not quite, the closest item would be the Alchemy Jug.

There is nothing in the way of detailed lore behind the Decanter of Endless Water, so it is entirely up to the DM what this looks like in their world - they may choose to create a Decanter of Endless Whisky if they wish. But, there does exist a canonical alternative.

The [Alchemy Jug](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/alchemy-jug) lacks the volume capabilities of the Decanter of endless water, but makes up for it in diversity.

The Alchemy Jug can produce acid, poison, beer, honey, mayonnaise, oil, vinegar, salt water, fresh water, and wine, at a rate of 2 gallons per minute in varying quantities, with a limit of 1 type of liquid per day.

Yes, [it can make mayonnaise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94262/why-is-mayo-in-the-alchemy-jug?r=SearchResults).

Comment: Just for folks not used to thinking in gallons: A low flow sink faucet produces about a gallon of water a minute; non-low-flow would be about two gallons per minute (my shower only uses 1.8 gallons per minute and it's pretty strong). Point is, if you don't need the firehose, the Alchemy Jug can produce a *lot* of whatever liquid you want. Just don't leave it running while you take a nap...

Answer (score 6):

The less-than-serious scenario pack for AD&D 1e *Castle Greyhawk* contains a Decanter of Endless Lemonade. And many other silly things.

Answer (score 3):

The Alchemy Jug (as mentioned above) would be closest, but also note that Hoard of the Dragon Queen p.74 contains a Tankard of Plenty.

> The Golden Tankard takes its name from a magic item that Raggnar found years ago: a golden stein decorated with dancing dwarves and grain patterns. This is a tankard of plenty. Speaking the command word (“Illefarn”) while grasping the handle fills the tankard with three pints of rich dwarven ale. This power can be used up to three times per day.

For lore/historical reference, this is similar to the Everfull Mug from 3.5e's Magic Item Compendium, p.160, which was possibly related to AD&D's Mug of Plenty (Encyclopedia Magica).

Comment: A gallon of ale or two gallons of mayonnaise - the decision is yours.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov How many are coming to the picnic and is anyone else bringing potato salad?